# android position TextView on "fixed" position on image

Tags: android, image, textview, location, fixed

I'm trying to display values that a user enters on an image, there are 4 versions of image (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi).
I want to position the textViews on a "fixed" location that adjusts to the right screensize.

Has anyone got some advice on how I could achieve this?

Here is a sketch of what I'm trying to do.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/251053/stackoverflow.png

*edit*

Thanks for the fast responses.
Uploaded a new image, this isn't possible with relative layout I guess?

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/251053/stackoverflow1.png

Comment: place in relative layout and set as centeralHorizontal="true" for left  textView one and centeralVertial="true" for top textView.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the problem is that the position of the text isn't the center all the time, it could be anywhere in the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the "RelativeLayout" documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html

You will be able to put your textView around your ImageView.

Comment: I added a new image of my goal, I guess that this isn't possible with relative layout?

Comment: Hum, with your new picture, I would say: "AbsoluteLayout", calculating the coordinates programmatically, but I'm not sure...

Comment: I've seen that as well but that class is deprecated, so is that the way to go?

Comment: So you can use a RelativeLayout, and modifying the margins of your TextViews programmatically, depending to where you want to put them...

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this I think is to create a custom layout that expects the ImageView as its first child.

All the other children will be the TextView's that you can either:

- position relatively to the position of your ImageView
- position proportionally to the height/width of your parent custom layout that matches the height/width of your ImageView

The left/top position information of the child TextView's can be given through a custom LayoutParams class that suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to create a custom view by extending View class. It is not so complicated as it may look. [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) you can find more info about custom UI components.

The main idea is to override onDraw(Canvas canvas) and onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) methods.
In onMeasure you should return the dimensions of your view and also you may calculate the size and angle of the rectangle and also the size of text you want to draw. Or you can implement custom resize() method that will be called explicitly on you view from the activity and make text and image calculations.

When you know all the measurements you can position and draw both image and text in onDraw(Canvas canvas) method.

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    myImageDrawable.setBounds(0,0,50,50);
    myImageDrawable.draw(canvas);

    canvas.drawText(myText, 10, 10, myTextPaint);
}
```

You can find more info about Canvas class [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html).
Also you may use [StaticLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/StaticLayout.html) to measure text.